# Remove Youtube preview animation on mouse over on youtube.com

Tags: browser, youtube, css, interaction

Browsing youtube.com is getting difficult for me as the mouse always triggers some animation somewhere. Is there a way to switch of youtubes mouse-over video "autoplay" feature on their website?

Ideally I would like to have some browser built in tool or a youtube setting. However, a ublock origin rule or a different browser extension would suffice too.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: This one is chrome, but Firefox would be fine too.

Comment: I use a couple of adblockers (on Firefox) and never see this behaviour.  I'm using Adblock Ultimate with no special plugins.  (Of-course, there could be a/b testing or something else that my experience is different to yours)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Greasyfork script: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/391615-disable-previews-on-youtube-firefox/code

It runs with TamperMonkey or GreaseMonkey.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tampermonkey

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey

Comment: This solutions works on some video thumbnails but not on all